# AngularJS current date validation

Tags: angularjs, validation, date

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm trying to validate a date field.  This is also my first ever question asked.  I've seen examples online but none seem to work for me, so my question is, can I validate within ng-show like indicated below.  I have a date field, which is formatted MM/dd/yyyy and I do not want myDateName field to be set to the current date. I thought something like this would work - am I close?

```
input type="text" ng-model="something.something" name="myDateName" ng-required="true" 

span class="error" ng-show="{{myDateName = new Date()}}">Can't be today's date<(close span)
```

I want to display an error message when myDateName equals current date.
I also tried `ng-show="angular.equals(myDateName, new Date())"` and that didn't work either, I'm quite frustrated.

I apologize in advanced if this is a duplicate question, I don't think it is but just in case, your time is valuable and I appreciate it as well as your advice.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help, it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can not use the `new` keyword in angular expressions. The rationale behind this rule is that business logic belongs in the controllers and not the views. This is part of a software design principal called `separation of concerns`. The primary purpose of a view is to display data.

> JavaScript expressions that have or promote side effects are prohibited, including:
>
> - assignments (=, +=, -=, ...)
> - **new**
> - chaining expressions with ; or ,
> - increment and decrement operators (++ and --)
>
> A template expression **should not change any application state** other than the value of the target property.
>
> This rule is essential to Angular's "unidirectional data flow" policy. We should never worry that reading a component value might **change** some other displayed value. The view should be stable throughout a single rendering pass.

My recommendation would be to create a separate function for determining a new date.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Answer (score 0):

The check should be

```
<span class="error" ng-show="something.something===today">Can't be today's date<span>
```

And you need to define today in the controller

```
var date = new Date();
$scope.today = date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try...

```
ng-show="isToday()"
```

and in you Controller have

```
$scope.isToday=function(){
  return $scope.myDateName==$filter('date')(new Date(),'mm/dd/yyyy');
};
```

Comment: curious, for this solution I get a $filter is not defined in my console.  Any idea why?

Comment: @Eddie You might have missed injecting $filter as dependency to your controller. Try doing that, and this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a directive for this, because it's a reusable solution, so here is:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMessages']);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.date = new Date().toLocaleDateString();
});

app.directive("weirdDate", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",

    link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$validators.weirdDate = function(modelValue) {
        return modelValue != new Date().toLocaleDateString();
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.5.7/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form name="form" novalidate>
    <input type="text" weird-date ng-model="date" name="date" required>
    <pre ng-bind="form.date.$error | json"></pre>
    <p ng-if="form.date.$error.weirdDate">Date can't be today! (without ngMessages)</p>
    <div ng-messages="form.date.$error">
      <p ng-message="weirdDate" style="color: #ff0000">Date can't be today! (with ngMessages)</p>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

As you may have noticed, I used [ngMessages directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages), you can read a good tutorial about them [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation-with-ngmessages).